# Develop and deploy React Native in the cloud

Tags: react-native, cloud

I'm searching for a cloud service to develop and deploy a React Native application.

That means I want to code online in the web browser and deploy the created .js file to the cloud. The native application (iOS, Android) is installed to the device locally via XCode or Android Studio. Only the reference to the bundled js file should be linked to file in the cloud.

My requirements are to code online in an online editor (like cloud9) and the bundled script should have a static URL.

Do you know which cloud service fits best to this use case?

Thanks for your tips!

Comment: Sorry but this is off-topic for StackOverflow: You're asking for a tool recommendation (cloud = tool), and which is best (which is opinion). This is also really broad, since there are *many* possible ways to solve this type of programming challenge. This might fit better in a discussion forum or blog post...

Answer (score 4):

There are two tools, [React Native Playground](https://rnplay.org/) for online editing and development and [code push](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/) for the deployment. There is no way to develop the way you would like to at the moment.

**EDIT**

It might be possible to develop this way using [Expo.io](https://expo.io/)

**EDIT 2**

React Native Playground was discontinued, but [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/) has the same mission

Comment: React Native Playground now links to an epitaph - Looks like the successor is Expo

Answer (score 4):

There is one way:

1. Register an account on [Cloud9 Online IDE](https://c9.io/)
2. Create a new blank Workspace:

   > Now you have a complete Ubuntu virtual machine running on Cloud With IDE features included.
3. Follow the [React Native Docs (Quick start)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

   > This will create you a react native project with Expo.io integration included. (Node is a prerequisite so install it ;)
4. Download Expo app on your phone, you will preview the app from there.
5. Start developing!

Comment: Hey Matteo, is Cloud9 free for react native development ? Won't it use much resources, which AWS will charge for ?

Comment: At the time of response Cloud9 was not part of AWS, I don't know if they offer a free tier as before

Answer (score 1):

I use [Appitr](https://appitr.com). It works pretty well. Comes with an emulator and It also reloads faster.

The only downside is that it has numerous restrictions on the free tier. Your project can't be downloaded, so you have to copy/paste to your local repo. And your repo must be open to the public. Other that these, I would give it an A+.

If you write Flutter, [Flutlab](https://flutlab.io) might be your best option considering it is cheaper at 9 bucks.

I have no affiliation with any of the mentioned services.